# php Laravel adding inputs with name as an array

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am trying to create a form where the names of the inputs are an array. I am going through an array sent from another view to get fields to show. in this example I want to show 3 fields.

```
$someResult = array('0','1','2');


$fields = array(0=>'fName',1=>'mName',2=>'lName');

@foreach($someResult as $k){

     <td> {!! Form::text($fields[$k][],$someVal) !!}</td>

@endforeach
```

I tried simplifing it to straight php:

```
  foreach ($someResult as $k){
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='".$fields[$k][]."' value='".$someVal."'></tD></tr>";
    }
```

Either way, i get the error "Cannot use [] for reading"

How can i declare name argument as an array?

My goal is something like:

```
   <td>
       <input type='text' name='fName[]' value='someVal'>
   </td>
   <td>
       <input type='text' name='mName[]' value='someVal'>
  </td>
  //etc.....
```

Comment: this is wrong `Form::text($fields[$k][],$someVal)` specifically `$fields[$k][]`  That last `[]` should be part of the name array `$fields = array(0=>'fName[]',1=>'mName[]',2=>'lName[]');`  etc.  Or as part of the "string" name, you could concatenate it etc... later of course `Form::text($fields[$k].'[]',$someVal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square bracket should be used as a string in your dom.

```
@foreach ($someResult as $k)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="{{ $fields[$k] }}[]" value="{{ $someVal }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```